# Characters of double groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

**Problem:**
I want to do some calculations with the character projection operator to investigate the irreducible representations of wave functions. Until now, I did these calculations for simple materials like Copper, where spin-orbit-coupling is not needed, and the corresponding groups are the normal point groups. Their charactertables can be calculated with several methods. One of these could be the method of Dixon and Schneider which is used by [GAP](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAP_%28Software%29). Now I want to calculate systems with spin-orbit-coupling, which results in the need for double groups. Unfortunately, the characters of the double groups are not the same, I calculate from rules from the literature (e.g. *Group Theory: Application to the Physics of Condensed Matter* by Dresselhaus et al.) compared with the results from GAP.

**Question:** Are double groups something special, so that none of the known algorithms used by GAP show the right result?

---

The rules I mentioned are, at first, the orthogonality relations for the rows and columns of the character table. ($h$ is the order of group $\mathcal{G}$, $N_k$ is the number of elements in class $\mathcal{C}_k$ and $\chi_i(R)$ is the character of element $R$ in the $i$-th irreducible representation)
$$\begin{align}
\sum_R \chi_i(R)\chi_j(R)^* &= h \delta_{i,j}\\
\sum_i \chi_i(\mathcal{C}_k)\chi_i(\mathcal{C}_l)^* &= \frac{h}{N_k}\delta_{k,l}
\end{align}$$
Furthermore, it is said, that if the elements of $\mathcal{G}$ and $\bar{\mathcal{G}}$ (which is not a group because of the missing unit element) form separate classes in the double group $\mathcal{D}$ (which is now the union of $\mathcal{G}$ and $\bar{\mathcal{G}}$) their characters have two relationships: In the "old" irreducible representations the characters of the classes are equal ($\chi_i(R) = \chi_i(\bar{R})$). In the "new" irreducible representations, their characters are of opposite sign ($\chi_i(R) = -\chi_i(\bar{R})$).

Comment: I believe GAP has this functionality built-in, but I can only find the more complicated versions at the moment. If $h$ is small (less than few thousand) there is a silly method that should work. Also if the group is famous, it is already pre-calculated for you.

Comment: In the end, I want to automatize the calculation of character tables with Mathematica. I used GAP as a reference to check for correctness of my implementation and noticed, that there are some problems, which I don't understand. Pre-calculated character tables are not an option because the user should be able to submit own groups.

Comment: How would you like the user to submit their group? Is it a 3-dimensional point group?

Comment: The user will usually submit the group as a matrix representation of any dimension.

Comment: @Stefan: there were no further discussions here. Why not to try to ask this in the [GAP Forum](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html)?